# someone ask me but don't know The script install.sh requires elevated permissions

Tags: linux

someone ask me but don't know The script install.sh requires elevated permissions to execute. Which command should be used to set execution permission?

chmod -r install.sh

chmod +x install.sh

chmod 400 install.sh

chmod -R 400 install.sh

chown install.sh

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Firstly, the file should be owned by the correct user. If yes, then executing `chmod +x install.sh` or `chmod 755 install.sh` should give execute permission to that file

Comment: That doesn't give it _elevated_ permissions, though. I'm guessing the OP is looking for setuid, but that's typically disabled for shell scripts.

Comment: last ask A Linux group, Dev, is unable to read and write the content of the file student.txt. Which of the following options grants the Dev group ownership of the student.txt file? chmod 600 dev student.txt or 
chown dev student.txt
 or 
chmod 400 dev student.txt
 or 

chmod 444 dev student.txt
  or
chmod dev student.txt